# Blank screen after using Bleachbit's "clear disk space" option - how can I recover?

Tags: boot, bleachbit

I was trying to free some space with Bleachbit and I selected the option **clear disk space**. After a while and making little space free the system hung and started to reboot but suddenly a blank screen appeared.

What can I do to fix this?

[image: black screen with OS: clean, 383878/1605632 files, 6409211/6420736 blocks]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know "bleachbit" it sounds like a home remedy for Covid .

However, I have a suggestion about what you might do: use the installation disk (really any version of Ubuntu or Mint ) and run gparted. It will tell you if the drive is really wiped, it shows the unused space in partitions.

Also, you could boot to the grub prompt, reporting back with what you see when you do these things, and a bit about our level of experience, might get the attention of a more knowledgeable contributor.

Good Luck!

Comment: sir robert_m , did you see the picture I've sent ?  if not the link is:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/leSQT.jpg

Comment: My browser only tells me "enter image description here"! Now I see the image, but it doesn't mean much to me: I do not know what "bleach bit" is supposed to do.  OS: clean ??? I don't think I can help.

Comment: @SeyyidehFatemehQarai are you able to boot from live USB and run `sudo fdisk -l` or gparted as suggested here? What I would suggest is to [run boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu) from the live system, get the info report and post it in your question. We can't help you with more specific advice to solve the problem without further information from you. However, boot repair is a generic tool which may be able to repair the problem that prevents your system from booting

Answer (score 0):

It seems BleachBit was working hard which made the system seem unresponsive, and the process was killed while the disk was full. This normally does not prevent booting, so there is [a FAQ](https://docs.bleachbit.org/doc/frequently-asked-questions.html) for this situation. In your case, try this

1. Boot from a "live" or "rescue" Linux system via CD or USB
2. Mount your /home drive
3. Run `rm -rf /home/username/.cache`

Of course, substitute the correct path for your user's folder. If you ran BleachBit as root, then try `/root/.cache`. In both cases, keep in mind the mounted folders may be an a different location when booting from a CD/USB.

For future reference, the option "wipe free space" does not create a net increase in free space. While it is running, the system may be very slow, and temporarily you will have less free space. When it's done (which can be a long time), previously deleted files will be unrecoverable. In other words, it wiped the space that was freed by previously deleted files.